# How can I remove null values from an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDDQC.png)

I want to remove the null value from the array, how should I do that?

I tried the following function, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem:

```
function removeNull(array) {
    return array.filter(x => x !== null)
}
```

Comment: We will need more details. Like how is the array loaded, if it is async and you try to run this code before the async operation is done the filter is going to happen before the array is even filled so you wont have actually filtered it. Are you checking the return value of the function or the original array for the change as the original array will not have changed.

Comment: Keep in mind it does not modify the original array. It gives you a new one.

Comment: it does solve the problem. But remember that `filter` does not modify `array` ~ instead returns a new array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to remove null values or undefined values from an array use the Array. filter() method to iterate over the array . check if each value is not equal to undefined and return the result. the filter() method will return the array which is new and does not contain any null values

Answer (score 1):

`.filter(x => x != null)` works as expected. You can shorten that to `.filter(Boolean)` if your array item values do not contain falsy values such as `0`:

```js
console.log('option 1: ', [0, 1, 2, null, 3].filter(x => x != null))
// [0, 1, 2, 3])
console.log('option 2: ', [0, 1, 2, null, 3].filter(Boolean))
// [1, 2, 3])
```